# Calculate numerical series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-calculus

I found an exercise that talks about calculating the value of a numerical series and we have the following two series of generic terms
$$
u_n = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n-\ln(n)}\right)\text{ and } v_n = \frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}
$$
Now we are asked to calculate
$$
U = \sum\limits_{k=3}^{+\infty} u_k \text{ and } V = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}v_k
$$
Um, and I'm really struggling to get started. Can you help me please?

Comment: This isn't very clear, sorry! As written, it looks like you want explicit expressions for $U_n$ and $V_n$, and that's (imho) pretty much hopeless. If you're interested in the numerical values of the infinite sums ($U_\infty$ and $V_\infty$), you should say so. The latter series converges rapidly, no problem, already 10 terms give reasonable precision. The former doesn't, because a billion terms can't guarantee 9 decimals, and if you (however unlikely that is) need 100 decimals, you're in trouble (or ask me ;).

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the error, thanks for the correction

Comment: Still, I can't seem to see the purpose of this exercise: calculation to what precision, error estimates, convergence acceleration (for $U$), analytic expressions (hopeless, if you don't count incomplete Gamma function at complex argument in case of $V$, but that's rather pointless)???